# Create an interface to communicate with another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I created an interface so I can set text on a FragmentB when I press a TextView on FragmentA. Something is not working and I can't figure this out.

I've created an interface called Communicator:

```
public interface Communicator {
void respond(String data);
```

}

On FragmentA I've set a reference on the interface called Communcator and an OnClickListener on the TextView:

```
Communicator comm;

homeTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            comm.respond("Trying to set text on FragmentB from here");
        }
    });
```

FragmentB, set my method to change text:

```
 public void setText(final String data) {
    startTripTxt.setText(data);
}
```

Finally in MainActivity I've implemented the interface .. I think here is where I'm doing something wrong:

```
 @Override
public void respond(String data) {

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_main, new FragmentB(), "fragment2").addToBackStack(null).commit();

    FragmentB fragmentB= (FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment2");
    if (fragmentB != null) {
        fragmentB.setText(data);
    }


}
```

Fragment 2 loads, but the text is empty.

Comment: well. I think the problem is in respond function in MainActivity When you call `commit()`, it didn't run in UI Thread, it take time to complete it, and then, fragmentB you declare after that will be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fragment 2 loads, but the text is empty.

You implement `Communicator` is ok but the way you call `FragmentB` and passing data is not ok. That 's is the reason why you cannot get text from `FragmentB`. the right way to send data to `FragmentB` should be like this:

```
public static FragmentB createInstance(String data) {
        FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", data);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

And  you can get data from FragmentB by:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
             String data = bundle.getString("data");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like after you declare fragmentB, you're meaning to set the text on that fragment.  You are Instead calling trainFinderFragment.setText().  Is that your issue?

```
FragmentB fragmentB= (FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment2");
if (fragmentB != null) {
    fragmentB.setText(data);
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question. FragmentB is actually called TrainFinderFragment but renamed it to FragmentB here so it is clearer for everyone.

Comment: Oh okay.  Yeah given your edit, you should take RoShan's advice above.  Pass in the text with a bundle.